# [PHP / PDO CLASS]Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I receive this error whenever I try to fetch something from my database using my PDO database wrapper:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 17`
**index.php**

```
require_once 'class.db.php';
$mysql = [
    'hostname'  => '127.0.0.1',
    'database'  => 'lucidcms',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'test',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
];
$db = new Database($mysql);

$u = "Sentinel";

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :u LIMIT 1")
             ->execute([':u' => $u])
             ->fetch();
echo $result;
```

**class.db.php**

```
<?php
class Database {

    private static $stmt, $pdo;

    public function __construct(array $mysql) {
        if(is_null(self::$pdo)) {
            try {
                self::$pdo = new \PDO(
                    'mysql:dbname='.$mysql['database'].';host='.$mysql['hostname'].';charset='.$mysql['charset'], 
                    $mysql['username'], 
                    $mysql['password'],
                    [\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true]
                );
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                die('An error occurred when trying to communicate with the database.');
                //die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            return new self;
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        // Destruct the connection to DB once finished
        try {
            self::$pdo = null;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die('An error occurred when trying to close the connection with the database.');
            //die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function prepare($sql) {
        self::$stmt = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        return self::$stmt;
    }

    public static function execute($data = []) {
        return self::$stmt->execute(isset($data) ? $data : null);
    }

    public static function count() {
        return self::$stmt->rowCount();
    }

    public static function fetch() {
        return self::$stmt->fetchColumn();
    }

    public static function fetchAll($type = \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
        return self::$stmt->fetch($type);
    }

    public static function lastId() {
        return self::$pdo->lastInsertId();
    }

}
```

I can't really seem to find out how to fix this error.
Any ideas of what I've done wrong?

EDIT, new working solution, but the coding is pretty messy:

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $host;
    private static $db;
    private static $dbuser;
    private static $pass;
    private static $char;

    private static $pdo, $stmt;  

    public function data($mysql) {
        self::$host   = $mysql['hostname'];
        self::$db     = $mysql['database'];
        self::$dbuser = $mysql['username'];
        self::$pass   = $mysql['password'];
        self::$char   = $mysql['charset'];
    }

    protected function __clone() {}

    public static function connect() {
        if(is_null(self::$pdo)) {
            try {
                self::$pdo = new \PDO(sprintf("mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;", 
                    self::$host,
                    self::$db), 
                    self::$dbuser, 
                    self::$pass,
                    [
                        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                    ]
                );
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                die('An error occurred when trying to communicate with the database.');
            }
        } else {
            return self::$pdo;
        }
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        // Destruct the connection to DB once finished
        try {
            self::$pdo  = null;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die('An error occurred when trying to close the connection with the database.');
            //die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function prepare($sql) {
        DB::connect();
        self::$stmt = self::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        return new self;
    }

    public static function execute($data = []) {
        DB::connect();
        try {
            self::$stmt->execute(isset($data) ? $data : null);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die("Execution error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
        return new self;
    }   

    public static function fetchAll($type = \PDO::FETCH_BOTH) {
        DB::connect();
        return self::$stmt->fetch($type);
    }

    public static function fetch() {
        DB::connect();
        return self::$stmt->fetchColumn();
    }

}
```

Any way to make the connect() and data() into a __construct() function?

Comment: Oh, make me unsee this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you did wrong, (**completely changed method names alone!**) but the error message you get is clear: if you want to use method chaining, you should  write every method just like prepare is written() - to make it return the statement.

However, this class couldn't be salvaged, as it will lead to nasty errors in production, due to its [statefulness](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#statefulness). Instead of this troublesome mess, let me suggest another solution, more lightweight and less error prone

```
class MyPDO extends PDO
{
    public function run($sql, $args = NULL)
    {
        $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

with this simple extension you will be able to use method chaining with your SELECT queries without the risk of messing your code up.

```
$result = $db->run("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :u LIMIT 1", [':u' => $u])
             ->fetch();
```

it is not that neat as your current approach but again - it doesn't bear its terrible drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: That's just awful.

Comment: Ikr, but I'm not really going to use, it's only for testing purpose.